# Interpretation of the term "Gate to Heaven"

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, vayeitzei, heaven

In [Genesis 28:17](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.28.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) it says:

> וַיִּירָא֙ וַיֹּאמַ֔ר מַה־נּוֹרָ֖א הַמָּק֣וֹם הַזֶּ֑ה אֵ֣ין זֶ֗ה כִּ֚י אִם־בֵּ֣ית אֱלֹהִ֔ים וְזֶ֖ה **שַׁ֥עַר הַשָּׁמָֽיִם**׃

The last 2 words' simple translation is "Gate to Heaven", as in a place from where prayers ascend to heaven.

Can this community share any other interpretations/commentaries that you came across for the terms "שַׁ֥עַר הַשָּׁמָֽיִם׃"?

Answer (score 2):

There are several sources:

1. [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.28.17?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Genesis.28.17.3&lang2=bi) - a place, that due to its location, acts as a direct channel of prayer. Since the location marked the place of the Temple, it mirrored the location of the Heavenly Temple:

> AND THIS IS THE GATE OF HEAVEN — a place of prayer where their prayers would ascend to heaven ([Pirkei DeRabbi Eliezer 35](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_DeRabbi_Eliezer.35.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). The Midrash states ([Genesis Rabbah 69:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.69.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) that the Heavenly Temple is situated immediately opposite the Earthly Temple (so that the Temple at Jerusalem-Bethel may be styled “the gate” to the Heavenly Temple)

2. [Ramban](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.28.17?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Ramban_on_Genesis.28.17.1&lang2=bi) - Since it was the location of the Temple, it represented the point of entry for his prayers.

> This refers to the Sanctuary which is the gate through which the prayers and sacrifices ascend to heaven.

3. [Sforno](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.28.17?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Sforno_on_Genesis.28.17.3&lang2=bi) - Similar to Ramban

> The gate. The ladder signified that it was from that place that prayers ascend to heaven.

4. [Bechor Shor](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.28.17?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Bekhor_Shor%2C_Genesis.28.17.1&lang2=bi) - It marks the spot where the angels enter and leave to do G-d's bidding.
5. [Chizkuni](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.28.17?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Chizkuni%2C_Genesis.28.17.3&lang2=bi) - A technical point based on Rashi.

> וזה שער השמים, “and this is the gateway to heaven.” According to Rashi, Yaakov referred to the Temple in heaven which is understood to be “opposite” the terrestrial Temple. If, you the reader were to ask how it is possible that the Temple in heaven is opposite that on earth, seeing that the site of that Temple had been moved by G-d, as we have explained?The answer is that it had been moved to be next to Yaakov. When Yaakov had traveled, the site of the terrestrial Temple had always moved with him, as the miracle had been performed for him and not for a piece of earth.

6. [HaKesav VeHakabbalah](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.28.17?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=HaKtav_VeHaKabalah%2C_Genesis.28.17.4&lang2=bi) - Notes how the heavenly realms work, how it represented a place where man will be considered for each and every thing. He brings the verse in [Tehillim 73:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.73.9?lang=bi)

> They set their mouths against heaven, and their tongues range over the earth.

7. [Kitzur Baal HaTurim](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.28.17?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Kitzur_Baal_HaTurim_on_Genesis.28.17.1&lang2=bi) a more practical understanding:

> This means that at dawn the gates of heaven are opened, and it is a good time to pray.

8. [Malbim](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.28.17?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Malbim_on_Genesis.28.17.1&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) - It marked the spot on earth where G-d "sat", in which the gate to heaven was open directly opposite through which prayers will go up to heaven to empty G-d's blessing.
9. [Mizrachi](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.28.17?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Mizrachi%2C_Genesis.28.17.8&lang2=bi) - The term "gate of heaven" is to be regarded as a parable because heaven has neither a gate nor a window, and is just an expression of the sages.
10. [Ohr HaChaim](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.28.17?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Or_HaChaim_on_Genesis.28.17.2&lang2=bi) - similar to other commentators already mentioned.

> When Yaakov said "this is the gate..." he meant that the place aligned with it above is the gate of heaven. This is why he used the word 'this' (zeh) twice.

11. [Rabbeinu Bachya](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.28.17?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rabbeinu_Bahya%2C_Bereshit.28.17.1-4&lang2=bi) - Firstly he notes that is represented a vision that Yaakov was shown:

> וזה שער השמים, “and this must be the gate to heaven.” The expression זה occurs three times in this verse. Bereshit Rabbah 69,7 therefore claims that G’d showed Yaakov a Temple built and destroyed; when Yaakov saw the Temple built, he exclaimed: “how awesome is this place!” When he was shown the Temple ruined, he exclaimed אין זה, “this cannot be!” When he was finally shown the Temple rebuilt, he exclaimed “this must be the gateway to heaven.” According to this version of the Midrash G’d showed Yaakov only two Temples.

He then notes:

> It is possible to explain our verse in a manner which shows that it contains allusions to all three Temples. It is a well-known fact that the word זה on occasion serves as an allusion to G-d

Like Rashi he notes the Pirkei DeRebbi Eliezer but builds on its meaning:

> There is a Midrash in Pirke de Rabbi Eliezer, 35 referring to the words: וזה שער השמים, “and this is the gateway to heaven.” According to this Midrash we learn from this verse that when one prays in Jerusalem one is as if praying opposite the gateway to the celestial Sanctuary, to the throne of G’d’s glory. The meaning of the Midrash is that from Jerusalem, the gateway to heaven, prayers ascend to their ultimate destination.

12. [Radak](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.28.17?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Radak_on_Genesis.28.17.4&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) - Brings a similar expression in Tanach where it demonstrates prayer directly reaching G-d in heaven:

> וזה שער השמים, an expression analogous to [Chronicles II 30:27](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Chronicles.30.27?lang=bi) ותבא תפלתם למעון קדשו לשמים, “their prayer reached the residence of His Holiness, to heaven.”

13. [Sifsei Chachomim](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.28.17?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Siftei_Chakhamim%2C_Genesis.28.17.4&lang2=bi) - Similar to Mizrachi:

> Its Midrashic ... the Heavenly Beis Hamikdosh is situated directly... It seems that the Midrash is not disagreeing. It is explaining why this is the place where prayers ascend: because it is right below the Heavenly Beis Hamikdosh. Nonetheless, “the gate of heaven” is allegorical; heaven has no gate or window. (Nachalas Yaakov)

14. [Tur Ha'Aruch](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.28.17?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Tur_HaArokh%2C_Genesis.28.17.1&lang2=bi) - Notes how it functions as a direct conduit to Heaven.

> “This must be the House of G-d, and at the same time the gateway to heaven” - This is a reference to the eventual Temple, the site from which the prayers of mankind will ascend to heaven without making any detours. The reason why prayers ascend more swiftly towards heaven from here, is the fact that they accompany the fragrance of the smoke of the various sacrifices.